# passing multiple data from controller to all views by view composer

Tags: laravel

My controller:

```
<?php
public function Dashboard()
{
    foreach ($roles as $item) {

        if (Auth::User()->hasRole("$item->name")) {
            $office_role = $item->name;
        }
    }
    $office_id = Auth::User()->office_id;


    $return_counter = Notification::where('recipient_office_id', $office_id)->where('recipient_office_role', $office_role)->where('status', 0)->where('type', 'Return')->count();

    $return_counter_pending = Notification::where('recipient_office_id', $office_id)->where('recipient_office_role', $office_role)->where('status', 2)->where('type', 'Return')->count();
    return view('Dashboard', compact('return_counter', 'return_counter_pending'));
}
```

I want to pass these data to all views by view composer. But how to Implement this, I tried but in boot method whenever I try to use the Auth I cannot access to login page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use blade template to pass these data from Controller to View, you can check how to use blade template from here. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade

Comment: no, I have to pass the data to master blade... so i have to use view composer or service provider

Comment: is master blade a layout blade for your view?

Comment: To display an Auth user data, you need to have a validation if user is already login or not by using if(Auth::guest)

Answer (score 0):

you may use this code inside your AppServiceProvider

```
  View::composer('*', function($view) {
    if(Auth::check()) {
      $view->with('foo', 'bar');
    }
  });
```

Or create a new View Composer
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers